# SignalR server API, and other platforms

Tags: signalr

I like SignalR and I am developing 2 things.

- Server side code
- Client web app

The challenge is that I need to allow the server to be implemented in a non .NET environments like may be Java or PHP. In that case the client will be using 
"SignalR" libraries and server has to match the SignalR implementation on the server (in PHP, Java, etc). **In a way, what I am after is shipping a server side API and a .NET signalr based implementation, but allow anyone to be able to implement the server side API in php/java etc**

For this, what I need the API sequence and protocol signalR uses. I am kind of thinking that this is not going to happen because SignalR is matched on the client and server side to talk in specific way to make the magic possible.

Has anyone else been in this predicament? Any ideas on what the best way to proceed? By the way, before you ask the question, if it is a pure websockets based app, I will have less problems, I can just user WebSockets standard APIs.
However, I might need to fallback on long polling, because my server might need to run on Windows 7 - where websockets is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reverse engineer the SignalR protocol make sure the clients do not have direct dependency on SignalR. Create client side adapters for the different server side framework. Include the correct adapter depending on server side platform

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) is a description of the SignalR protocol.